# Clear input field with driver.find_element_by_xpath().clear()

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have one input box where have numbers, I want to clean it but when call

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/form/section/div/div/input').clear()
```

they not remove. If I run same from Python Shell it working. Tried with timeout but can't clear.

I need to sendkeys

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/form/section/div/div/input').send_keys('50')
```

Tried

```
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/form/section/div/div/input').clear()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/form/section/div/div/input').send_keys('50')
```

and result is `2050`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a common problem with newer versions of chromedriver on selenium. I found a hacky solution in just sending a bunch of backspace keys to the selected web element.

```py
for i in range(100):
  WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)
```

Could even do

```py
for i in range(len(current_field_value)):
  WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)
```

Comment: `for i in range(20):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/form/section/div/div/input').send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)`

This working

Comment: If the cursor is at the beginning of the field, backspace won't do anything.  Where does selenium put the cursor?

Comment: Interesting point @JohnGordon [Selenium Docs] (https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_Selenium_DefaultSelenium_SetCursorPosition.htm) I found this related to selenium cursor movement, which you could use to move the cursor to the end before backspace. I havent tried to use it in python gonna test it out